# Removing the zero in the chapter numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, chapters

I have a line of code to hide "Chapter" and just head every chapter in the format `"ChapterNumber" + "." + "ChapterTitle"`.
However, the Table of Contents is assumed to be `"Chapter 0"`, so it shows `"0. Contents"`. Is there any way to hide this "0." so it shows "Contents" only?

Code used:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE\thechapter.~}
```

[image: How the zero appears in the Contents table]

Comment: In the KOMA-Script classes your wish is the default behaviour, you might want to have a look. `scrreprt` is the corresponding class to standard `report`. Also note that usage of `\bf` is **deprecated since 1994**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that I used `\bfseries` instead of the long, long deprecated `\bf` and used `\arabic{chapter}` to format the number, you might also want to try `\Roman{chapter}` for example.

### Update: second version (thanks to egreg)

As this answer is the checked one, I'll include egregs more correct one, which uses correctly the possibilities of `\titleformat`, which has 4 mandatory arguments:

`\titleformat{<command>}{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}`

- `<command>` is the sectioning command you want to change, in your case `\chapter`.
- `<format>` are text formatting commands to be applied, you want to use `\bfseries\Large`
- `<label>` formats the label if the chapter is numbered, it is left out when not. You want `\arabic{chapter}.~`
- `<sep>` is the hspace between `<label>` and the actual title, set it to `{0pt}`
- `<before-code>` is arbitrary code that should be called before the title is typeset

So your version of `\titleformat` should be:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\Large}{\arabic{chapter}.~}{0pt}{}
```

### First Version, you should not use this:

You can check if `\thechapter` is greater than zero:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bfseries\LARGE\ifnum\value{chapter}>0\relax\arabic{chapter}.~\fi}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test I}
\chapter{Test II}
\end{document}
```

Output:
Table of contents:

[image: Table of Contents]

First Chapter with some blindtext:

[image: Chapter 1]

Comment: This is not the right way...

Comment: I see, i will delete this and upvote egregs answer, if this gets unchecked.

Comment: @MaxNoe It should be `\ifnum\value{chapter}>0`, not `\ifnum\thechapter`, as you don't know whether `\thechapter` expands to a number.

Comment: Your answer is far more elegent anywasys ;)

Answer (score 6):

You want a different way to use `\titleformat`. The third mandatory argument to `\titleformat` specifies what's used for numbered chapters, while the final argument specifies the title proper; in this case nothing apart printing the title should be done.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter.\ }{0em}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test I}
\chapter{Test II}
\end{document}
```

[image]