# LaTeX report class - Removing the word 'Chapter' but keeping the numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters, report

I'm writing a LaTeX document using the report document class.

By default, when a new chapter is initiated, say with the title 'Introduction', it is presented on a new page in the following manner:

Chapter 1

Introduction

In the Table of Contents, this appears as '1. Introduction'.

I would like the chapters to instead be presented as

1. Introduction

But, I would also like to keep the form in the ToC, i.e. '1. Introduction'.

I have tried applying \renewcommand{\chaptername}{}, which has removed the 'Chapter' heading. However, the Chapters are then presented with just their title, i.e. 'Introduction'. If I manually change these titles to '1. Introduction' etc, they appear as '1. 1. Introduction' in the ToC.

Could anybody please advise me on how to do this? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `titlesec` package and [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). The following command should allow you to achieve such formating:

`\titleformat{〈command〉}[〈shape〉]{〈format〉}{〈label〉}{〈sep〉}{〈before-code〉}[〈after-code〉]`

- `〈command〉` is the sectioning command to be redefined, i. e., `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph` or `\subparagraph`.
- The paragraph shape is set by `〈shape〉`.
- `〈format〉` is the format to be applied to the whole title—label and text.
- The label is defined in `〈label〉`.  You may leave it empty if there is no section label at that level, but this is not recommended because by doing so the number is not suppressed in the table of contents and running heads.
- `〈sep〉` is the horizontal separation between label and title body and must be a length (itmust not be empty).
- `〈before-code〉` is code preceding the title body.
- `〈after-code〉` is code following the title body.

This is my suggestion:

`\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{}{1em}{\thechapter.~}`

Comment: Thanks! This (almost) did the trick. It has had the unfortunate effect of changing the Contents heading to '0. Contents'. Any idea how I could remedy this?

Comment: Try adding `\thispagestyle{fancy}` before the `\tableofcontents` command. this will change the style for that page from `display` to `fancy`.

Comment: Hasn't worked unfortunately:( Still the same.

Comment: Strange. I was able to reproduce the issue with '0. Contents'. Which style did you modify with the `\titleformat` command?

Comment: This answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229669/removing-the-zero-in-the-chapter-numbering gave a solution. I'm new here - should I delete this post?

Comment: Ok, I see. In that solution they don't use the `shape` argument. 

I'm also new here, but I think there is a way to mark this question as a duplicate of the other question.